# Moving Access 2016 application's data from Access to SQL Server 2016

Tags: migration, sql-server-2016, ms-access-2016

I have a seemingly straight forward project, which unexpectedly faces many obstacles.

I need to move backend data of the existing Access 2016 application from Access to SQL Server 2016.

The challenges I face are:

1. The simplest and recommended way to migrate Access to SQL Server is using Microsoft SQL Server Assistant (SSMA) for Access.  The problem is that my Access is 32-bit Click-to-Run edition.  Because the target is SQL Server 2016, I should use SSMA for Access v.7.6.0, which is available only in 64-bit.  To use it, I need to install 64-bit Access Runtime, which could not be installed, because per the error message “Windows Installer and Click-to-Run editions of Office programs don't get along”.  The earlier version of SSMA for Access 6.0 comes in 32-bit and connects to Access fine, but could not connect to SQL Server 2016, as 2014 is the latest version it supports.  Ignoring the warning and forcing the connection to SQL Server 2016 causes error collecting data…  Thus, I could not use SSMA.
2. I was able to migrate the data from Access to SQL Server using SSIS.  Now, my challenge is to repoint existing Access tables to their SQL Server copies.  I was trying link, but it appears that existing Access tables could be linked only to the file system data source.  If I try to make link from the SQL Server side, I could only create new linked tables, which do not do me much good as I am trying to avoid massive changes in the application.  Could it be that I am missing something simple here?..
3. Some Access tables have columns of attachment data type.  SSIS doesn’t handle attachment data type correctly.  To the best of my knowledge, neither does SSMA.  So, when I get to link Access tables to SQL Server, I would probably need to write some code to move attachments from the backup Access database to SQL Server.  Is there some other an easier solution?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. That is correct. It is a mess. You can use another (virtual) machine with a clean 64-bit Access install.
2. Delete the current tables in the frontend and link the SQL Server tables. They may be given a "dbo_" prefix which you can remove by renaming the tables.
3. This is a rewrite. Attachment fields are not supported in SQL Server. Neither are other fancy features like lookup fields and multivalue fields.